# What the difference between iTunes and App Store search results?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, itunes-store

I see difference in positions of applications in search result of iTunes (on PC and web) and App Store (on devices).

What is the key difference on it and why does it differ?

Comment: I Guess the Difference is based on screen because Apps are developed based on liquid platform so it varies.

Answer (score 1):

Found it: App Store has special User Agent:

'User-Agent': 'AppStore/2.0 iOS/8.1 model/iPhone7,2 build/12B411 (6; dt:106)'

Comment: Do you know user-agent for iPad?